# Density of continuous functions in $L^{p}$ and Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I have learnt that $C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ is dense in $L^{p}(U)$ where $U$ is open, $1\leq p<\infty$. I have also learnt that $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $W^{1,\,p}(I)$ when we restrict the sequences in $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ to the interval $I$, $1\leq p<\infty$.

Now does the density of $C_{c}^{\infty}$ in both cases give me density of all $C_{c}^{k}$, $k\geq 1$? does this also extend to $C_{c}$?

I guess what I am trying to get at is, are the function spaces $C_{c}^{k}$ nested? With the largest being $C_{c}$?

Comment: If $A\subset B\subset C$ and $A$ dense in $C$, then $B$ is also dense in $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\mathcal C^\infty_\mathrm c = \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal C_\mathrm c^k$. Thus, in particular, $\mathcal C^\infty_\mathrm c \subset \mathcal C_\mathrm c^k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Since every differentiable function is continuous, we also have $\mathcal C_\mathrm c^k\subset\mathcal C_\mathrm c$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$.

By the statement below, we thus have that all $C_\mathrm c^k$ and $C_\mathrm c$ is dense in $W^{1,p}$.

**Statement.** If $A\subset B$ and $A$ is dense in $X$, then $B$ is also dense in $X$.

Comment: That's what I thought but I couldn't find it stated anywhere in literature, so I just wanted to be sure. Thank you for your explanation.